# As an American, if I get a Master of Modern Languages in Italy, how hard would it be to get into an American PhD program?

Tags: phd, masters, career-path, europe, language

As an American, if I get a Master of Modern Languages in Italy, how hard would it be to get into an American PhD program?

***My end goal is to be a professor of one or two languages at an American University*** but I want to do my Master's in Italy, studying French, Spanish and German, (studying through Italian.)

*How hard would it be for me, if I had great grades and recommendations, to then get into a reputable PhD program in America afterwards?*

I'm thinking about somewhere in Tuscany because that's where I have lots of friends and family, so either Pisa or Siena University.

**More details:**

1. I'm bilingual in Italian, I can read well enough to read adult literature, and I write well enough to be mistaken for a native. (My accent gives away I'm a foreigner during longer conversations.)
2. I could become an Italian citizen, (I have all the necessary paper work, I just haven't brought it to the embassy yet.)
3. I want to do my Master's in Europe, because whenever I'm in America I get sucked back into my English/Spanish/Italian life, and I get rusty at my other languges, (I speak 6 "world" languages "fluently", (three languages at C1/2 and three at B2/B2+).

Comment: and then a PhD in what?? (the connection between the MA you're describing and your later plans is opaque without that).

Comment: "adult" literature or literature beyond kids books?

Comment: @AzorAhai Written works intended to be read by fully literate native speakers.

Comment: Location of friends and family is generally not the best argument to choose a university program...